Cumulative values using a formula?
I'm trying to create a cumulative column using other colums value and I cant seem to get it right using formulas. Im getting recursive errors if I try to use index().
Here what I try so far
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x8A3ldlG8SUlus5_kgnNrWrY_nQ-lfMpk7HOv-Gvif8/edit?usp=sharing
I tried using Let():
Let say I have Column G & H. H(x) = G(x) + H(x-1)
=LET(sq,SEQUENCE(B5,1,0),ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(E10:E,sq)+SI(sq=0,0,DECALER(INDEX(G10:G,sq),-1,0))))
Thank you so much for your time!

You can use the SCAN function:
=SCAN(,E10:E33,LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))



Thanks for the answer. E10:E33 seem to be a hardcoded range. If I change my month number (B5), column doesnt adapt

You can replace E10:E33 with the formula that is generating the range.

I tried sequence(B5;1;0) without success, or maybe you can pinpoint a best way to do it? thank you!

That's not the formula in column E. The formula that's generating the range is: =ArrayFormula(ROUND(RANDARRAY(B5)*B6)).

I dont see how it help me to put a randarray there? =SCAN(,RANDARRAY(B5),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))

what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you manually enter the desired result in sheet?

What you did, but just needed to be dynamic regarding the nb of rows in (B3). But just achieve it using INDIRECT("E10:E"&NbRows)

doesn't this work? =SCAN(,ArrayFormula(ROUND(RANDARRAY(B5)*B6)),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)) I simply replaced E10:E33 with the formula that's generating the range.

No sorry, it generates a new set of values instead of picking the one already generated

hmm, how about you try this?
=SUM($G$10:G10)

If this doesn't help let me know!

If I change my month number, column do not adapt. its why im looking for a formula. Thank you for your answer. I learned something new still
